# How can I send userid from form request to pre_ or post_delete signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-signals

Another question form novice.
I have some form:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
def save(self, commit=False):
 instance = SomeModel(field='value1')
 instance.userid = self.request.user.id
 instance.delete()
 instance = SomeModel(field='value2')
 instance.userid = self.request.user.id
 instance.save()
```

In post_save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=SomeModel)
def pre_save_model(sender,instance,**kwargs):
 print(instance.userid)
```

it works fine.
But in post_delete:

```
@receiver(post_delete,sender=SomeModel)
def post_delete_model(sender,instance,**kwargs):
 print(instance.userid)
```

it says:

```
AttributeError: 'SomeModel' object has no attribute 'userid'
```

I guess, than I can't understand something important. But what?

**Update:**

*I realized:*

That was an error :

```
instance = SomeModel(field='value1')
instance.userid = self.request.user.id
instance.delete()
```

should be

```
instance = SomeModel.objects.filter(field='value1')
instance.userid = self.request.user.id
instance.delete()
```

So, instance is an QuerySet. Further it must be processed for every object of instance:

```
def save(self, commit=False):
 queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(field='value1')
 for instance in queryset:
  instance.userid = self.request.user.id
  instance.delete()
 instance = SomeModel(field='value2')
 instance.userid = self.request.user.id
 instance.save()
```

Comment: Can you show us your `SomeModel`?

Comment: This is an abstract example.